# How do I write a GatewayFilter that adds a principal name as a request parameter?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to write a `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter` that adds a principal name as a request parameter (let's say the param should be called `clientId`). Limitations:

1. `getPrincipal()` returns not a `Principal` but a `Mono<Principal>` so I have to pass some callback right away which seems challenging in this case
2. I can't `block()` without getting something like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: blockOptional() is blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingOptionalMonoSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingOptionalMonoSubscriber.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException
```

3. `ServerWebExchange` is immutable
4. Java lambdas can only take final or effectively final variables

Here's `GatewayFilter`'s abstract method:

```java
Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain);
```

So basically I need to implement this:

```java
GatewayFilter addPrincipalNameAsParamFilter() {
    return (serverWebExchange, gatewayFilterChain) -> // ...
}
```

A (non-working) attempt at doing it:

```java
return (exchange, chain) -> {
    Mono<Principal> principalMono = exchange.getPrincipal();

    return principalMono.flatMap(principal -> {
        String principalName = principal.getName();

        ServerWebExchange updatedExchange = exchange
                    .mutate()
                    .request(requestBuilder -> 
                       requestBuilder.path(exchange.getRequest().getPath() + "?clientId=" + principalName).build())
                    .build();
        return chain.filter(updatedExchange);
    });
}
```

The code above ensures that first the endpoint is hit and then the lambda gets executed (which is the other way around). If only I could block to get the principal

Gateway has some out-of-the-box filter factories, but it appears it only fits if you pass static values (yes, you have to wrap it in `OrderedGatewayFilter` for some reason, otherwise it won't work)

```java
return routeInConstruction.filter(
           new OrderedGatewayFilter(
               new AddRequestParameterGatewayFilterFactory()
                       .apply(nameValueConfig -> nameValueConfig.setName("clientId").setValue("hard-coded_principal_name")), 0
           )
       );
```

How can (should) I achieve my goal?

## UPD

I tried to implement Tavark's suggestion. Here's an MRE to show that it doesn't work (if I implemented it correctly):

### Gateway

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewaydemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewaydemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.constant;

public enum JWT {

    KEY("jxgEQeXHuPq8VdbyYFNkANdudQ53YUn4"),
    HEADER("Authorization"),
    ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION("3600000"),
    REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRATION("3600000"),
    UUID("uuid");

    private final String value;

    JWT(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.security;

import com.example.gatewaydemo.constant.JWT;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.ReactiveSecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter implements WebFilter {

    private static final SecretKey KEY = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JWT.KEY.getValue().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        String jwt = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(JWT.HEADER.getValue());

        if (jwt != null) {
            try {
                Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(KEY)
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                        .getBody();
                String clientId = String.valueOf(claims.get(JWT.UUID.getValue()));
                Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(clientId, null, null);
                return chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(auth));
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                log.error("Token has expired. " + e.getMessage());
                return createError(exchange, e);
            } catch (SignatureException e) {
                log.error("Token signature cannot be verified. " + e.getMessage());
                return createError(exchange, e);
            } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
                log.error("Token is not properly formatted. " + e.getMessage());
                return createError(exchange, e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error parsing token. " + e.getMessage());
                return createError(exchange, e);
            }
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    private Mono<Void> createError(ServerWebExchange exchange, Exception e) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(createErrorBody(e.getMessage())));
    }

    private DataBuffer createErrorBody(String errorBody) {
        byte[] bytes = errorBody.getBytes();
        return new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.context.NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter = new JwtAuthorizationFilter();

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        final var permitAll = new String[]{
                "/api/v1/registration/**",
                "/api/v1/security/**",
                "/api/v1/login/**",
                "/api/v1/exchange-rates/**",
                "/api/v1/bank-branch/**",
                "/api/v1/error-message",

                "/actuator/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/swagger-ui-config",
                "/*/doc"
        };
        return http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers(permitAll).permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingSpec -> exceptionHandlingSpec
                        .authenticationEntryPoint((exchange, ex) -> Mono.fromRunnable(
                                () -> exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        )))
                .cors(corsSpec -> corsSpec.configurationSource(corsConfiguration()))
                .build();
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
        config.setMaxAge(Duration.ofHours(1));
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.routing;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import java.net.URI;

@Configuration
public class MyRoutingConfig {
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder) {
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
                .route(predicateSpec -> predicateSpec
                        .path("/api/v1/hello-world")
                        .and()
                        .method(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec.rewritePath("/api/v1", "/auth")
                                .filter(addClientIdAsParamFilter()))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8090")
                ).build();
    }

    private GatewayFilter addClientIdAsParamFilter() {
        return (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
                .flatMap(principal -> {
                    URI newUri = UriComponentsBuilder
                            .fromUri(exchange.getRequest().getURI())
                            .replaceQuery("?clientId=" + principal.getName())
                            .build(true)
                            .toUri();

                    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange
                            .getRequest()
                            .mutate()
                            .uri(newUri)
                            .build();

                    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
                });
    }
}
```

```yaml
server:
  port: 8070
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatewaydemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gatewaydemo</name>
    <description>gatewaydemo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
        <jsonwebtoken.version>0.11.5</jsonwebtoken.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Microservice

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloworldMreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloworldMreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.controller;

import com.example.helloworldmre.data.SuccessMessage;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.text.MessageFormat;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@Tag(name = "Message Controller")
public class MessageController {
    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public SuccessMessage getHelloWorld(@RequestParam(required = false) String clientId) {
        return new SuccessMessage(MessageFormat.format("hello world to client {0}!", clientId));
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.data;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class SuccessMessage extends Message {
    public SuccessMessage(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.data;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class Message {
    private String message;

    public Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

```yaml
server.port=8090
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworldservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloworldservice</name>
    <description>helloworldservice</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Curl

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8070/api/v1/hello-world' \
--header 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwidXVpZCI6ImNhOTk0ZTk3LThjNDctNDM3YS1iN2Y3LWFjYzYxYTY5NmEyOCIsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.z9hnbc7RgrePm-N8S7eYdWoN75jKDgPL9tlHXlgvR-w'
```

[image]

### Response

```json
{
    "message": "hello world to client null!"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change this (what Tavark suggested)

```java
(exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
                .flatMap(principal -> {
                    URI newUri = UriComponentsBuilder
                            .fromUri(exchange.getRequest().getURI())
                            .replaceQuery("?clientId=" + principal.getName())
                            .build(true)
                            .toUri();

                    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange
                            .getRequest()
                            .mutate()
                            .uri(newUri)
                            .build();

                    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
                });
```

to this

```java
                new OrderedGatewayFilter(
                        (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
                        .flatMap(principal -> {
                            URI newUri = UriComponentsBuilder
                                    .fromUri(exchange.getRequest().getURI())
                                    .queryParam("clientId", principal.getName())
                                    .build(true)
                                    .toUri();

                            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange
                                    .getRequest()
                                    .mutate()
                                    .uri(newUri)
                                    .build();

                            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
                        }), 0);
```

it works at least *sometimes*. Go figure

Answer (score 1):

I have had a quite similar issue. Below I tried to adapt your problem on top of my solution. Hope this helps.

```
public class AddCliendIdRequestParameterGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractNameValueGatewayFilterFactory {


        @Override
        public GatewayFilter apply(NameValueConfig config) {
            return (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
                    .flatMap(principal -> {
                        var newUri = UriComponentsBuilder
                                .fromUri(exchange.getRequest().getURI())
                                .replaceQuery("?clientId=" + principal.getName())
                                .build(true)
                                .toUri();

                        var request = exchange
                                .getRequest()
                                .mutate()
                                .uri(newUri)
                                .build();

                        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
                    });
        }
    }
```

Then I could add it like that into my filterchain:

`.filters(new AddCliendIdRequestParameterGatewayFilterFactory()`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I still get the same problem. The param is `null` (( (even if I wrap it in `OrderedGatewayFilter`). I'll try to tinker with a little... Maybe, I'll be able to fix something up...

Comment: By param you mean the principalName? 
Is your Spring Security configured properly? How do you call your Gateway?
Are you sending any tokens through the Gateway?


For my use case I'm using Oauth2 and have added [TokenRelay GatewayFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/gatewayfilter-factories/tokenrelay-factory.html)

Comment: Please see the edit